# Firebase rules setValue only if a child exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to use rules but it's not working.

Here is the structure :

[image]

I have this command :                     `DeleteItemFromListRef.child("List").child(obj.getsEventID()).child(ID).child("check").setValue(false);`

But I want to set the value to "false" only if the child (key) exists so that if the item is deleted, I will not simply have that :

[image]

Here is my rules :

```
 "List": {
    "$listID" : {
      "$key": {
        "check" : {
      ".write":"data.child('List').child($listID).child($key).child('key').exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

}

But still, if the child key is empty, it still uploads the data like this :

[image]

if anyone can help, would be nice

EDIT 2: here are much simpler rules

```
"rules": {






           "List": {
            "$listID" : {
               "$key": {
                 "check" : {  
".read":"auth.uid != null", 
".write":"auth.uid != null", 
".validate":"data.parent().child('key').exists()"

}
}}}}}
```

+COMMENTS :

So I always update the item with a map if I add a new one, but if I change only the child **"check"** I use the **"setValue"** method and want the setValue to be done only if the item is already there `(== child key already exist)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to allow writing `checked` if its sibling property `key` exists, you can do:

```
"List": {
    "$listID" : {
        "$key": {
            "check" : {
                ".validate":"data.parent().child('key').exists()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update** Since you're having trouble making this work, I just tested it in a very simple setup. Under `/55431756` in my database, I have this JSON:

```
{
  "has_key" : {
    "key" : "value"
  }
}
```

So it's a single key `has_key` that has a `key`. Now I ran two simulations: one trying to write to `has_key`.

Writing to `has_key` succeeds, since `has_key/key` exists:

[image: Writing to <code>has_key</code> is allowed]

Writing to `no_key` is denied, since there is no `no_key/key` child:

[image: Writing to <code>no_key</code> is denied]

Comment: It is not working, I still got this https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIcRQ.png when I setValue to false and that the item is not there... I edited question with all of my rules

Comment: Permission cascades downwards. Once you give permission at a certain level in the tree, you can't remove it at a lower level. So the `".write" : "true"` and `".write":"auth.uid != null"` in your original rules override the more restrictive `.write` at the lower levels. However the `.validate` should always be ANDed. Can you reproduce the problem with smaller JSON and rules, so that I can test them?

Comment: What do you wean by "ANDed"? 
So if I understand well, If I want to use separate rules for all of my child, I souldn't use at the beginning : "".read":"auth.uid != null", 
".write":"auth.uid != null", " because it will always be that rules for the read and write since it is the higher place in the tree?

I edited my rules like you suggested + comments.
Thank you for your time

Comment: I just ran a test on my own database, and the rules do what I'd expect them to do. I'm not sure what is happening in your setup, which is why I shared the entire test I did.

Comment: Thank you Sir it works better now. I understand better the way it works, it was really helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can also first check whether the child exists and upon true perform the above command.